# Javascript regex with optional capture groups - matching a mongo query

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I'm trying to write a regex to parse a Mongo type query like this:

```
db.users.find({
    name : 'Joe Black'
})
```

or this:

```
db.users.updateMany({
    name : 'Joe Black'
}, {
    foo : 'bar'
})
```

**Goal :** I'm trying to extract the 2 objects {} in this string seperately. The 1rst object is required, the 2nd is optional.

Parsing the 1rst string should return

```
{
    name : 'Joe Black'
}
```

Parsing the 2nd string should return

```
{
    foo : 'bar'
}
```

**What i've got so far** is this regex, which gets me part of the way:

```
^(?:db\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\()({(.|[\r\n])*})(?=\))
```

which you can try out here : https://regex101.com/r/lQ4lE4/1

Currently the regex I have is just capturing everything in {} brackets.

Breakdown of my current regex:

1) Non-capture group that matches the string 'db.user.updateMany('

```
^(?:db\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\()
```

2) Capture group that matches everything in brackets {}

```
{(.|[\r\n])*})
```

3) Positive lookahead to assert that end is a )

```
(?=\))
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
^(?:db).*.(?:[a-zA-Z0-9])\(({(.|[\r\n])*})(?=(?:[,\r\n])*)(?=\))
```

which is the same regex, but has a positive lookahead for

```
' , '
```

**What I can't figure out is how to optionally capture the 2nd set of brackets, separate from the first.**

Comment: Something like [`^db\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(({[\s\S]*?}(?=\s*,|\)))(?:\s*,\s*({[\s\S]*?})(?=[),]|$))?`](https://regex101.com/r/pS7eS6/1)?

Comment: this looks very promising, thanks! do you mind making an answer from this, with some explanation of the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like

```
/^db\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(({[\s\S]*?}(?=\s*,|\)))(?:\s*,\s*({[\s\S]*?})‌​(?=[),]|$))?/gm
```

The regex matches:

- `^db\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(` - a `db.<alphanum+>.<alphanum+>(`-like sequence
- `({[\s\S]*?}(?=\s*,|\)))` - Capture group 1 matching:

  - `{` - opening brace
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any number of any characters up to the first
  - `}` - literal closing brace that is...
  - `(?=\s*,|\))` - immediately followed by 0 or more whitespace symbols and a comma or a literal `)`
- `(?:\s*,\s*({[\s\S]*?})‌​(?=[),]|$))?` - and optionally match the following sequence:

  - `\s*,\s*` - 0 or more whitespace followed by a comma followed by 0 or more whitespace
  - `({[\s\S]*?})‌​(?=[),]|$)` - capture group 2 matching:

    - `{` - opening brace
    - `[\s\S]*?` - as few any symbols as needed to get to the first...
    - `}` - closing brace that...
    - `(?=[),]|$)` - is followed by `)` or `,` or end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS7eS6/1)

Comment: wow @stribizhev this is great. I was having trouble figuring out how to match the {...} pattern, but only up to a comma + whitespace. Will need to study your answer a bit. thanks for the help!

Comment: It is a mixture of an optional non-capturing group (`(?:...)?`) and a look-ahead anchored lazy dot matching approach. This is not an efficient approach, since very long strings might cause a timeout (similar to catastrophic backtracking) issue. You can unroll the regexp using unroll-the-loop regex technique. Let me know if you have any trouble with the current regex and I will dwell more on that.

Comment: this works on regex101.com, but when I try it in my code I'm not getting a match. Here's a fiddle using regex101's generated code, also giving a null match. https://jsfiddle.net/0p38gpdw/

Comment: Check this [updatred fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfyvfh1y/1/). You are using the `m` variable outside the `while` block where it is not initialized.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense thanks! ran into another problem tho, since the brackets can contain other brackets. https://jsfiddle.net/yb937y77/

Comment: would it be more performant (due to the issues you mentioned in your comment above) to do this a different way? maybe with multiple regexes?

Comment: It depends on how many nested levels there are. My kids are not yet asleep, I can't help now, but there is a way to use a recursive regex search.

Comment: No problem, and thanks again for all your help, very much appreciated. both of the objects parsed could contain many levels of nested brackets, I just need to parse each object. The way I've been doing this so far is using 2 regexes. 1 to just match and validate https://regex101.com/r/sQ9cP4/2, and a 2nd to pull out the objects https://regex101.com/r/sQ9cP4/4.

Comment: I have been trying to adapt some code from [this blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-recursive-regexp), and could come up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hehad8ct/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^(?:db\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\()({[^{}]*}\s*,?\s*)+
```

See [RegEX demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ4lE4/2)

Comment: This will choke on `foo : 'bar{}'`.

Comment: yea still not quite working for db.foobar.update({}, {})   https://regex101.com/r/sN5hJ8/1